# Select MAX value from two tables: which one is better

Tags: mysql, select, max, select-query

I have two ways to select MAX values from two tables but don't know which one is better or faster.
i checked from `mysql workbench` but in case both query i'm getting `0.00 Sec` execution time

**First query**

```
SELECT MAX(s) from (
  SELECT sheetid  s FROM csheets
  UNION all
  SELECT sheetid s FROM queueitems
) as t
```

Explain
[image]

**Second Query**

```
SELECT MAX(s) from (
  SELECT MAX(sheetid)  s FROM csheets
  UNION all
  SELECT MAX(sheetid) s FROM queueitems
) as t
```

Explain
[image]
So question is which one better in terms of speed?

Comment: I guess instead of using `MAX` you can use `order by sheetid desc limit 1`

Comment: First create indexes on `sheetid` column for both tables--> `CREATE INDEX indexname1 ON csheets( sheetid )` and `CREATE INDEX indexname2 ON queueitems( sheetid )`, this is a must, because at present both queries perform full table scans. Then run explains again and post results.

Answer (score 1):

The second one would be better, because the aggregation is performed before, you will have one step less on the temporary table than with the first query.

However take a look at the execution plan, with the EXPLAIN .

Comment: to look at what in explain for decisoin

Comment: i have updated the question with Explain which may help more in getting appropriate answer